# 'declared as a function' in C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LIMIT 100

/* Stack structure */
typedef struct stack
{
  char x[LIMIT][10];
  int top;
  void push(char *s);
  char *pop();
  void init();
  bool is_empty();
} stack;


/* Reset stack's top */
void stack init()
{
  this->top = 0;
}
```

And codes go on but It gives that error:

```
main.c|14|error: field 'init' declared as a function|
```

What is wrong? I can not figure out it since yesterday. Please help me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Structures, in C, cannot have functions. They can, however, have pointers to function.
You need to redefine your `struct stack`.

Example without functions or pointers

```
struct stack {
    char x[LIMIT][10];
    int top;
};

void push(struct stack *self, char *s);
char *pop(struct stack *self);
void init(struct stack *self);
bool is_empty(struct stack *self);
```

Example with function pointers

```
struct stack {
    char x[LIMIT][10];
    int top;
    void (*push)(struct stack *, char *);
    char *(*pop)(struct stack *self);
    void (*init)(struct stack *self);
    bool (*is_empty)(struct stack *self);
};

struct stack object;
object.push = push_function; // function defined elsewhere
object.pop = pop_function;   // function defined elsewhere
// ...
```

Comment: main.c|20|error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '.' token|  object.push = push_function; line givesds that error, why?

Comment: how can you call pushfucntion without arguments?

Comment: `object.push = push_function;` is not a function call, it is a pointer assignment. It assigns the address of the function to the pointer. To call the function through the pointer the usage is `object.push(&object, "string");`

Comment: i need help struct stk;    stk.push=push_function;
     stk.push(&stk,infix[i]); but error

Comment: Did you try the version without functions or pointers? Unless you have a good reason to simulate C++ in C, use that version. Otherwise try C++ (which, I believe, makes it easy to work with functions the way you appear to want).

Comment: my school only accepts C for project. i did this C++ last year and want to convert to C, because it is hard to code again. i tried with function pointers, i tried other but i couldnot figure out how to call them. with function ppointers, it seems easier. but program after getting input, shuts down.

Answer (score 3):

C cannot hold functions inside structs. But, you can place a function pointer.

```
void (*init)();
```